# jtable selectionlistener doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I have write a little program with a table in it, i've tried and read so many documentation and anwers but i really don't understand what am i doing wrong, because the 4th column is still editable and no event is triggered when i select the rows...

## Main

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private JLabel banner;

    private String[] tecnici;
    private String[] columnNames;
    private Object[][] data;
    private JTable table;
    Map<String,List<Cliente>> clientiList;
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);

    Main(){
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        ImageIcon webIcon = new ImageIcon(Constants.WORK_GUI_LOGO);
        setIconImage(webIcon.getImage());

        setTitle(Constants.WORK_GUI_TITLE);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        banner=new JLabel("", webIcon, JLabel.CENTER);

        MenuBar menu=new MenuBar();

        setJMenuBar(menu.getMenuBar());

        System.out.println("Leggo i tecnici dal db");
        tecnici=new String[] {"Tarzan","Cita","Jane"};

        clientiList=new HashMap();

        for(String tec:tecnici){
            List<Cliente> l=new ArrayList<>();
            Cliente c=new Cliente();
            c.setConsultivoIncassi(1000);
            c.setNome("Clnl ross");
            c.setPreventivoIncassi(1000);
            l.add(c);
            c=new Cliente();
            c.setConsultivoIncassi(2000);
            c.setNome("Clnl ross");
            c.setPreventivoIncassi(2000);
            l.add(c);
            clientiList.put(tec, l);
        }
        data=createTableFromMap(clientiList);
        columnNames=new String[]{"Tecs","Customer","count","credit"};
        table=new JTable(data, columnNames){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                //where i want to make editable only the 4th col
                return col==4;
            }

        };
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new TableSelectionListener());

        createWindowLayout(
                banner,
                new JLabel("Tecnici"),
                new JCheckBox(tecnici[0]),
                new JCheckBox(tecnici[1]),
                new JCheckBox(tecnici[2]),
                new JTable(data, columnNames));
    }

    public void createWindowLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        pane = getContentPane();
        gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);        

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(arg[0])
            .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(arg[1])
                    .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(arg[2])
                        .addComponent(arg[3])
                        .addComponent(arg[4])                                   
                        )
                    )   
            .addComponent(arg[5])
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(arg[0])
            .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[1])
                .addComponent(arg[2]))
            .addComponent(arg[3])
            .addComponent(arg[4])
            .addComponent(arg[5])
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                Main ex = new Main();
                ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private Object[][] createTableFromMap(Map<String,List<Cliente>> clienti ){
        Iterator it= clienti.entrySet().iterator();
        Object[][] tabella=new Object[clienti.size()][4];
        int counter=0;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry entry=(Map.Entry) it.next();
            for(Cliente c:(List<Cliente>)entry.getValue()){
                tabella[counter]=new Object[]{entry.getKey(),
                        c.getNome(),
                        c.getPreventivoIncassi(),
                        c.getConsultivoIncassi()};
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return tabella;
    }

    class TableSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener{

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            String selectedData = null;

            int[] selectedRow = table.getSelectedRows();
            int[] selectedColumns = table.getSelectedColumns();

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < selectedColumns.length; j++) {
                    selectedData = (String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow[i], selectedColumns[j]);
                  }
            }
            System.out.println("Selected: " + selectedData);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *"because the 4th column is still editable and no event is triggered when i select the rows..."* SO is not a help desk, but a Q&A site on chich you've failed to ask a question. So which matter do you wish to deal with on this thread, and what's your question?

Comment: You failed to read your own code to the point where you have a comment saying: "make only editable 4th row" above a line that checks for 4th column. You will get help, because there's plenty of people desperate for karma or diversion (hey, that's me as well!) - but the question shows complete lack of respect for anyone who does answer.

Comment: The comment is wrong, i want to make editable only the 4rth columns, but despite what i have written everything is stille editable. I don't want to lack respect to anyone, i want to undertstand what am id oing wrong, sorry if you feel disrispected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return col==4;
```

Did you ever do any basic debugging to see that the value of the "col" variable is? The first thing you should do when you have a problem is used System.out.println(...) to display the value so you can determine if your if condition is correct.

If you did, you would have noticed two things:

1. You don't get any output because the code is never executed.
2. Even is it did execute it would not work because your table only has 4 columns and Java uses 0 based offsets should you should be using "3" for the 4th column.

The reason the code is never executed is because you have two table. The first one you create with the overridden isCellEditable() method. But you never add that table to the GUI so that is dead code. Then you create a second table that you add to the GUI:

```
new JCheckBox(tecnici[2]),
new JTable(data, columnNames));
```

So get rid of the above statement and just use:

```
new JCheckBox(tecnici[2]),
//new JTable(data, columnNames));
table);
```

Since the table variable is the table with the custom method.

Comment: ohh thanks you are the only one who have seen the error, yes I was re initializing the table, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at your code and comment here:

```
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //where i want to make editable only the 4th row
            return col==4;
        }
```

The comments don't match the code do they? Your method is checking col when it should be checking row, no? e.g.:

```
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //where i want to make editable only the 4th row
            return row == 4;  // ****** note change ******
        }
```

---

MCVE'ized code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel banner;

    private String[] tecnici;
    private String[] columnNames;
    private Object[][] data;
    private JTable table;
    Map<String,List<Cliente>> clientiList;
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);

    Main(){
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        ImageIcon webIcon = new ImageIcon(Constants.WORK_GUI_LOGO);
        setIconImage(webIcon.getImage());

        setTitle(Constants.WORK_GUI_TITLE);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        banner=new JLabel("", webIcon, JLabel.CENTER);

        MenuBar menu=new MenuBar();

        setJMenuBar(menu.getMenuBar());

        System.out.println("Leggo i tecnici dal db");
        tecnici=new String[] {"Tarzan","Cita","Jane"};

        clientiList=new HashMap<>();

        for(String tec:tecnici){
            List<Cliente> l=new ArrayList<>();
            Cliente c=new Cliente();
            c.setConsultivoIncassi(1000);
            c.setNome("Clnl ross");
            c.setPreventivoIncassi(1000);
            l.add(c);
            c=new Cliente();
            c.setConsultivoIncassi(2000);
            c.setNome("Clnl ross");
            c.setPreventivoIncassi(2000);
            l.add(c);
            clientiList.put(tec, l);
        }
        data=createTableFromMap(clientiList);
        columnNames=new String[]{"Tecs","Customer","count","credit"};
        table=new JTable(data, columnNames){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                //where i want to make editable only the 4th row
                return col==4;
            }

        };
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new TableSelectionListener());

        createWindowLayout(
                banner,
                new JLabel("Tecnici"),
                new JCheckBox(tecnici[0]),
                new JCheckBox(tecnici[1]),
                new JCheckBox(tecnici[2]),
                new JTable(data, columnNames));
    }

    public void createWindowLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        pane = getContentPane();
        gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);        

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(arg[0])
            .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(arg[1])
                    .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(arg[2])
                        .addComponent(arg[3])
                        .addComponent(arg[4])                                   
                        )
                    )   
            .addComponent(arg[5])
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(arg[0])
            .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[1])
                .addComponent(arg[2]))
            .addComponent(arg[3])
            .addComponent(arg[4])
            .addComponent(arg[5])
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                Main ex = new Main();
                ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private Object[][] createTableFromMap(Map<String,List<Cliente>> clienti ){
        Iterator it= clienti.entrySet().iterator();
        Object[][] tabella=new Object[clienti.size()][4];
        int counter=0;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry entry=(Map.Entry) it.next();
            for(Cliente c:(List<Cliente>)entry.getValue()){
                tabella[counter]=new Object[]{entry.getKey(),
                        c.getNome(),
                        c.getPreventivoIncassi(),
                        c.getConsultivoIncassi()};
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return tabella;
    }

    class TableSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener{

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            String selectedData = null;

            int[] selectedRow = table.getSelectedRows();
            int[] selectedColumns = table.getSelectedColumns();

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < selectedColumns.length; j++) {
                    selectedData = (String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow[i], selectedColumns[j]);
                  }
            }
            System.out.println("Selected: " + selectedData);
        }

    }

    private static class Cliente {

        private String nome;
        private int preventivoIncassi;
        private int consultivoIncassi;

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setPreventivoIncassi(int preventivoIncassi) {
            this.preventivoIncassi = preventivoIncassi;            
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public void setConsultivoIncassi(int consultivoIncassi) {
            this.consultivoIncassi = consultivoIncassi;
        }

        public int getConsultivoIncassi() {
            return consultivoIncassi;
        }

        public int getPreventivoIncassi() {
            return preventivoIncassi;
        }

    }

    private static class Constants {

        public static final String WORK_GUI_LOGO = null;
        public static final String WORK_GUI_TITLE = null;

    }

    private static class MenuBar {

        public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @fdreger *What* 'question'? Copy/paste it here. I've voted to close as "unclear what you're asking".  Since you seem to be clear on that, please enlighten me.

Comment: @fdreger: no, I've been diving in code that I MCVE'ized (see above). Lord knows why but I guess I felt like empty work for nothing.